# ORA-06502 when connecting to Oracle 12c using new SQL credentials

Tags: oracle

Hi I'm trying to connect to an Oracle 12c instance using a connect descriptor and newly created SQL credentials. But when I try to connect using the credentials I get:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 18
```

I managed to track down possible documentation on this to: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1274538_1.html

But unfortunately I don't have an Oracle Support Account to view the details. My personal guess is some logon PL/SQL (a trigger or procedure) is running and there might be an issue with the information retrieved for the credentials I've been given. Because of the recursive SQL level error, I think something like NULLs are being returned for some expected entry in some kind of dictionary/lookup table when the PL/SQL runs. I'd appreciate if any one may know why this could happen. In the mean time I'll get in contact with the DBA to investigate.

**Update**

The DBAs got back to me and helped by modifying the trigger. Nothing additional was required by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added in the oracle support link. The conjectures are true but the "character string buffer too small" error shows that the table has been worked to write a great value 
that the column is allowed. Whichever table the trigger records in, you need to look at the column sizes in that table.

---

**SYMPTOMS**
A new user is created who tries to connect to Oracle:

SQL> create user test identified by  default tablespace users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to test;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect test/
ERROR:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 7
CHANGES
New user created.

---

**CAUSE**
Like in this case, the issue can be caused by an existing logon trigger.

---

**SOLUTION**
Connect as sysdba and disable the trigger.

SQL> select trigger_name from dba_triggers where triggering_event like '%LOGON%';

SQL> alter trigger  disable;